# External IP redirects to router page

Tags: router, ip, redirection, xampp, wamp

I'm having a small problem here.

I'm running wampserver and I'm trying to access it externally so I could use it as a webserver for others to view my projects using my external IP

I forwarded the port 8080 in my router to my internal IP address, I made sure my IP address is static, I forwarded the port in my firewall to allow private and public traffic on it

If I access it using `localhost:8080`, `127.0.0.1:8080`, it works perfectly. If I try to access it using my external IP it redirects to my router page, if I try to access it using myIP:8080 it says that the page was not found

So why is my external IP being redirected to my router page and how can I solve the issue so others can connect to my IP like a webserver?

I'm using an Aztech 605EW router

Comment: Are you sure you wamp server listen on Lan ip address and not only localhost ?

Comment: Depending on your router, you may need to tell your router to forward requests for that IP to your WAMP Server.

Comment: `if I try to access it using myIP:8080 it says that the page was not found` What is "myIP" external or internal ?

Comment: external IP, that is

Comment: Can you try `internal_ip:8080` ?

Comment: It says forbidden

Answer (score 3):

Very likely, it's expected behaviour of the router.

The router looks at each packet, and attached to it is the IP Address of the *source* and the *destination*. If it's destined for the outside world, outside your local range, the router sends it to the WAN interface, and down the chain, awaiting its reply. If it is asking for an address on the LAN side, it simply sends it on the interface that matches that address.

But, your external IP address, coming from the inside? I know of very few routers that process the rules the way you are hoping. All the home-based routers I've owned have this behaviour, where typing in the router's external address from inside the network brings up the configuration page (if it's enabled).

Another option you can try, if you can't connect from *outside* your network and back in, would be to check that the Remote Management section of your router is not enabled for WAN access. It's possible that the router is using that for its own administration. You can also try setting your server in the DMZ zone of the router's Firewall configuration. This will expose that ONE computer to the Internet, so typing in your external address sends everything to that computer (minus anything you explicitly indicated to go elsewhere via port forwarding)

Comment: My router has an option called `Web Access Control`, do you think that has anything to do with it? I can enable it and disable it, If I enable it I need to input a remote host IP, remote netmask and redirect port.

Comment: Edited my comment.

Comment: Look for anything relating to Remote Management or Remote Administration

Comment: Nothing in relation to that. However, I found `routing`. does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: It's possible, but we'd really have to look up the manual to your router. But I still believe that's expected behaviour, while you're inside the network

Comment: Do you think there's any workaround to allow people that are not on my network to access my webserver?

Comment: Connecting from a friend's place and seeing if you can hit it... Basically, you need to remove yourself from the network, leaving the computer that's hosting the website there, and try to hit it

Comment: @ali You can try connecting to an external proxy and then connecting to your external IP address. Since you're connecting from a Proxy server from the internet, the router should forward it back to your machine properly.